# Counting vertices and adding it as number to column using shapely

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, vertices, count

I have a small `DataFrame` and created new column. I would like to add to every record in column `"vertex_counter"` value of n. I have the problem because it is doesn't work and I have in every record in column `"vertex_counter"` value `0`.

What can be the problem?

```py
df_budynki3 = df_budynki
df_budynki3['vertex_counter'] = 0

for index_budynku, bud_row in df_budynki3.iterrows():
    coo = shapely.wkt.loads(bud_row['classification.geometry']) # create polygon from string
    n = len(coo.exterior.coords) # count number of points in polygon
    bud_row['vertex_counter'] += n
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

In [Modify pandas DataFrame within iterrows loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61696479)

> The rows you get back from iterrows are copies that are no longer connected to the original data frame, so edits don't change your `DataFrame`. However, you can use the index to access and edit the relevant row of the `DataFrame`. (for `bud_row['vertex_counter'] += n`)

Therefore you can assign  values in the loop using [pandas `.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html?highlight=#pandas.DataFrame.at) (or [pandas `.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc)):

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")

gdf['vertex_counter'] = 0

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
  gdf.at[index,'vertex_counter'] = len(row['geometry'].exterior.coords
  # or gdf.loc[index,'vertex_counter'] =  len(row['geometry'].exterior.coords

print(gdf)
    name        geometry                                    vertex_counter
0   uno  POLYGON ((-0.59330 0.68268, -0.55084 0.32737, ...        8
1   dos  POLYGON ((0.01229 -0.30726, 0.05922 -0.21117, ...        8
2  tres  POLYGON ((0.34749 0.57318, 0.80559 0.60894, 0....        5
```

But if you look at [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758) or [pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) ("You should never modify something you are iterating over") it is preferable to use

The apply function

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")

gdf['vertex_counter'] = gdf.apply(lambda row: len(row.geometry.exterior.coords),axis=1)

print(gdf)
    name        geometry                                    vertex_counter
0   uno  POLYGON ((-0.59330 0.68268, -0.55084 0.32737, ...        8
1   dos  POLYGON ((0.01229 -0.30726, 0.05922 -0.21117, ...        8
2  tres  POLYGON ((0.34749 0.57318, 0.80559 0.60894, 0....        5
```

The [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) method

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")
n = [len(geom.exterior.coords) for geom in gdf.geometry]
gdf['vertex_counter'] = n
print(gdf)
    name        geometry                                    vertex_counter
0   uno  POLYGON ((-0.59330 0.68268, -0.55084 0.32737, ...        8
1   dos  POLYGON ((0.01229 -0.30726, 0.05922 -0.21117, ...        8
2  tres  POLYGON ((0.34749 0.57318, 0.80559 0.60894, 0....        5
```

With `itertuples()` and [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
gdf['vertex_counter'] = [len(i.geometry.exterior.coords) for i in gdf.itertuples()]
```

With `iterrows()` and [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
gdf['vertex_counter1'] = [len(row['geometry'].exterior.coords) for index, row in gdf.iterrows()]
```

Eventually, you can also create a new empty `GeoDataFrame` and populate it:

```py
gdf = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")

gdf['vertex_counter'] = 0

new = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=gdf.columns)

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
     row['vertex_counter'] = len(row['geometry'].exterior.coords)
     new = new.append(row)
```